# How can i get specific values from array use for in loop

Tags: javascript, for-in-loop

Hello i have the following array:

```
var data = [
    {
        title: "title 1",
        data2: [
            "content",
        ]
    },
    {
        title: "title 1",
        data2: [
            "content",
        ]
    }
];
```

how can i get title & data2 values in loop ?

Thanks so much.

edit:

The problem has beed solved with the help of a cat @Niklas Higi but,

how can i get values to my html template in .append function :

```
<div class="data">
    <div class="data-item">
        <h6>'+data.title+'</h6>
        <ul>
            <li>contents from data2 value</li>
        </ul>
    <div>
<div>
```

i need get data2 values to li tags.

Comment: what is the expected output? Please share an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(let item of data) {
  console.log(item.title);
  console.log(item.data2);
}
```

Please note that I have used `for of` and not `for in` as your tag suggested. `for in` iterates over the indices (in case of an array `0`, `1`, ...) while `for of` iterates over the items (`Object`'s in your case).

---

**Answer to your edit:** In the `for` loop create the elements that you need with [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and add them to your `.data` container using [`.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild). For the `<ul>` you can just create another `for of` loop to go over the list items and add them to a `<ul>` tag you created with `document.createElement()`.

Comment: thanks for your response, @Niklas Higi, i updated my question, if you available please help me ?

Comment: I edited my post to address your other question.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Iterate through array
data.forEach((item) => {

    // Do stuff with items here, 
    // using dot-notation. We will
    // just log them in this example.

    console.log(item.title);
    console.log(item.data2);
});
```